# IOS twitter app to add image

Tags: ios, xcode, image, twitter

I'm creating an application that has integration with Twitter .. and wanted to know what have to do to create a button to add an image of the device in the tweet.and also wanted to know which framework to use it and also where the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the twitter framework, it's included since iOS 5

And the code i use:

```
- (IBAction)twitter:(id)sender {
    if([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
    {
        NSLog(@"Ready to Tweet.");   
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetComposer = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [tweetComposer setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My message"]];
        [tweetComposer addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"114x114"]];
        [tweetComposer addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myPage"]];
        tweetComposer.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result){
        if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone){
            NSLog(@"Tweeted.");

        } else if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Cancelled.");
        }

        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        };
        [self presentModalViewController:tweetComposer animated:YES];
    }else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops"
                                                        message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Twitter account setup"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
}
```